# Python web frameworks comparisons

Tags: python, web-framework, django

I recently asked a question on SO about Python web frameworks:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909306/python-web-frameworks-vs-java-web-frameworks-how-is-web-development-in-python-do

I want to learn one just for fun but it also has to be able to help me deliver a proper working application.

I am looking for a framework with lots of features, powerful, mature, with large community, good documentation, books etc. I need something that will help me be more productive in developing my app and not waste time figuring out how to do a certain thing in the framework or how to write workaround around the limitations of the framework.

I was thinking one of the following: django, zope, turbogears, pylons.

Off course the war is raging out there and there are other alternatives but seems [Django is at the top](http://www.google.com/trends?q=django,+zope,+turbogears,+pylons&ctab=0&geo=all&date=all&sort=0)... or is it just hype?

I am interested in pros and cons of each. What was the best feature you think the framework has? What is the thing it lacks? What could have been done differently.

Help me chose one to learn for starters.

Comment: Have you thought of Web2Py? (http://web2py.com/)

Comment: @Jetti: I also thought of web2py along with others. [There are plenty](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks) to choose from :D. In my question I mentioned the ones that are the most utilized and with lots of features (at least from what I researched and read). But I could be wrong since I am new to this. I am opened to other suggestions as well.

Answer (score 2):

- Django is at the top for a reason: it rocks!
- Zope is much older, that also means it's more mature; but has lots of legacy and some say bloat.
- haven't tried turbogears, but it seems its main point is interoperability, letting you choose the exact mix of components you want.  that also means each setup is unique, and community support might get fragmented.
- Pylons is another "mix your own", with a focus on minimalism.